# Suppose $(y_n)$ is a convergent sequence. Prove that if $y_n <= b$ for infinitely many n then $lim (y_n) <= b$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(y_n)$ is a convergent sequence. Prove that if $y_n \le b$ for infinitely many n then $lim (y_n) \le b$.

Here are my thoughts for starting the proof:

I attempted first by proving the contrapositive: Assume that if $lim (y_n) > b$, then $y_n \le b$ for finitely many n-values.

Since $y_n$ is convergent, it is also bounded (this is known using a theorem from the textbook). This means that there exists a k in the real numbers such that $|y_n| < k$ for all n.

I am trying to figure out ways to go from here but I am stuck.

Comment: Please make the body of your posts self-contained: don't rely on the title to convey important information (such as the statement of the problem). I've done an edit on your behalf. Also note that MathJax supports a wide range of mathematical symbols: "\le" gets you a much nicer less-than-or-equal sign than "<=".

Comment: ... As for the maths: if the limit, $y$ say, is greater than $b$, feed $\varepsilon = (y-b)/2$ into the convergence property and it will give you (infinitely many) $n$ such that $y_n > b$.

Comment: hint: give a name to lim($y_n$), say L (> b), and pick a suitable tiny neighborhood of L. $y_n$ is bounded, you are right, but you really need to use convergence - a stronger condition.

Answer (score 3):

Let $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n$. If $l>b$, then $l-b>0$ and therefore there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that if $n\in\Bbb N$ and if $n\geqslant N$, then $|l-y_n|<l-b$. But then, if $n\geqslant N$,$$l-y_n\leqslant|l-y_n|<l-b,$$and threfore $y_n>b$. So, the inequality $y_n\leqslant b$ can only take place when $n\in\{1,2,\ldots,N-1\}$ and there are only finitely many such numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: having infinitely many elements of a sequence which satisfy some property means you can create a subsequence of such elements.